# LINQのOrderBy処理をキャンセルしたい

Tags: c#, linq

LINQのOrderByのソート処理をキャンセルするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

**目的**
運用では、自前の文字列比較クラスを使って数万単位の文字列をソートすることがあるのですが、これに数秒の時間がかかっており、この処理を中断したいときがあります。

**試したこと**
CompareメソッドでCancellationTokenを使ってOperationCancelExceptionをthrowするようにしてみたのですが、VisualStudioのデバッガーにユーザー処理されていない例外として中断されてしまい、かつソート外部にはInvalidOperationExceptionの例外として投げられてしまいます。 (VS2022 .NET6.0)

以下、テスト用のサンプルコードになります。

```cs
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Reverse().ToList();

// このソート処理を CancellationToken でキャンセルしたい
var sorted = items.OrderBy(e => e, new HeavyComparar()).ToList();

public class HeavyComparar : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);  // heavy compare process dummy
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: 自前の文字列比較クラスの方が気になります。例えば`OrderBy()`は安定ソートなのでその分コストがかかります。`List<T>.Sort()`や`Array.Sort()`では不安定ソートなので若干早いとか。大文字小文字の区別をしない場合、大文字化してから大文字小文字を区別する比較をした方が早くなれるかもしれないとか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CompareメソッドでCancellationTokenを使ってOperationCanceledExceptionをthrowするようにしてみたのですが、VisualStudioのデバッガーにユーザー処理されていない例外として中断されてしまい、かつソート外部にはInvalidOperationExceptionの例外として投げられてしまいます。

InnerExceptionに、OperationCanceledException が入ってるんじゃないでしょうか。

```cs
try
{
    _CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    var sorted = items.OrderBy(e => e, new HeavyComparar()).ToList();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    if( ex.InnerException is OperationCanceledException )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("キャンセルされました");
    }
}
```

Comment: InnerExceptionで判断可能であることを確認できました。ただ、デバッガーにユーザー処理されていない例外として処理されてしまうのが気になります。

Comment: 私の環境では中断されませんでしたが、デバッグ⇒ウィンドウ⇒例外設定 で、中断する例外を確認してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: 例外設定ではSystem.OperationCanceledExceptionにチェックは入っていないのですが、そのコンテキストメニューで「ユーザーコードで処理されない場合は続行します」にチェックを入れることでこの例外キャッチを抑制できることがわかりました。他の処理の例外キャッチにも影響してしまいそうなのでなるべく標準設定のままにしたいです。

Comment: そうなってくると、最悪CancellationTokenを引数に取れるOrderBy相当の拡張メソッドを自作するしかなさそうな気がします…が、それも不毛すぎるので、デバッグ中は中断する事を許容するかどちらですね。ロジック的には問題ないと思いますし。Releaseでは中断しないですよね？

Comment: はい、デバッガだけでの問題になります。この挙動もありCompare()にキャンセル処理を実装するのは邪道のように思えたので、LINQ処理をキャンセルする正攻法があればと思いこの質問を投稿しました。

Comment: Visual Studio から［デバッグ(D)］⇒［デバッグの開始(S)］でアプリを実行すると try - catch で OperationCanceledException を捕捉できないという話であればこの記事が参考になるかも⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/07/17/cancel-parallel-for-loop.aspx

Comment: 記事のとおりに「マイコードのみを有効にする」設定をOFFにしたところ、個別の例外設定をしないでも期待通りの例外取得ができるようになりました。この方法は良さそうです。

Comment: 私も確認してみたら、既にOFFになってたから中断されなかったんですね。昔同じように例外をcatchしてるのに中断された記憶はあったんですが、その時何の設定を変えたか覚えてなかったんですよねぇ。